# how to know which buttons submits the form php

Tags: php, forms, button

i have two buttons of type submit in my `view`:

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="Excel">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>&nbsp; Download as Excel
 </button>

 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="Resume">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>&nbsp; Download Resume
 </button>
```

and `controller`:

```
if ($this->input->post('Resume')) {
  echo "Resume Clicked";
}

if ($this->input->post('Excel')) {
  echo "Excel Clicked";
}
```

i would like to know that which button has submitted the form for that i have written the above code..but i am not getting any `echo` after clicking any of the button..

i don't want to use here:

`<input type='submit' name='excel' value='Excel'/>`

`<input type='submit' name='excel' value='Excel'/>`

as it works with the type 'input' i would like to use `button` of `type` `submit`

Comment: Why don't you want to use `<input />`?

Comment: @BrianWarshaw because of the css that i have used for type button....well i got my solutions thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a value to the button, ie:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" name="Resume" value="true">
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt"></span>&nbsp; Download Resume
 </button>
```

You will have a $_POST['Resume'] with value "true" in your backend code.

Ofcourse something like: `name="buttonName" value="Excel"` and another button with `name="buttonName" value="Resume"` would make have a `$_POST['buttonName']` with its value either being 'Excel' or 'Resume'.